# TimeZone property in Retrieve Calls

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I am trying to use TimeZone property in the Retrieve calls for Account and BusinessUnit object but it throws an error

```
<Properties>TimeZone</Properties>
```

> The Request Property(s) TimeZone do not match with the fields of Account retrieve

Documentation says that it can be used and will return the timezone of the Account/Business Unit.
Do I need to specify this in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the properties of the TimeZone object you're looking to retrieve:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
     <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-24440876" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Username>{{Username}}</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">{{Password}}</wsse:Password>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
  <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
     <RetrieveRequest>
        <ClientIDs><ID>12345</ID></ClientIDs>
        <QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts>
        <ObjectType>Account</ObjectType>
        <Properties>TimeZone.ID</Properties>
        <Properties>TimeZone.Name</Properties>
     </RetrieveRequest>
  </RetrieveRequestMsg>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```